# JavaScript how to program button to act like a mouse click?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm trying to program a button to act like a mouse click event using ONLY JavaScript (NO jQuery)

For example if you have:

```
<h2> Please select your fav: </h2>
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" class="checkbox" /><label for="check1">C++</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check2" class="checkbox" /><label for="check1">Java</label>
<input id="submitAnswer" type="button"  value = "Submit your Answer" onClick="submitAnswers()">/input>

<input id="mouseClick" type="button"  value = "CLICK" onClick="mouseClick()"></input>
```

So, I have a focus method, which checks what element has focus.
I need to program another button to act like the mouse click, so in case of clicking on the checkboxes, it should check/uncheck it. and if the focus on the submit button, it should trigger the function.

Comment: Ummm jQuery is javascript....

Comment: You realise that using the space bar will emulate click behaviour on a checkbox and radio?

Comment: The requirement of the project is not to use any framework.

Comment: @davidThomas I know that. but, I need to do it using soft keys on the screen

Comment: @GabrielFlorit, I'm not a student ... 
this is a side project I'm working on... Thanks anyway...

Comment: If you're not to use any frameworks, just how robust do you want this? Because there are a lot of cross-browser problems here, that jQuery handles. If you want that level of compatibility, be prepared for a lot of work reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @KRyan supporting webkit should be enough for this scope

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = document.getElementById('submitAnswer');

input.click(); //simulate click event
```

Comment: I've tried that, This will trigger any "onClick()" methods, but it will not work on the checkboxes/radio buttons as well as any onMouseUp() events

Comment: I was under the impression that there were all sorts cross-browser annoyances with that.